# Columns with its own scroll taking the 100% of available space of a 100vh container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to have 3 columns with its own scroll, but taking 100% of available space.

But there's no scroll, or they don't get the 100% of the available space.

Important that the body has not to have scroll (that's the reason of the 100vh of the container), and the header takes the space its contents need. Can't be fixed.

If I add "100vh to each column" ... the columns goes further the bottom.

If I add the overflow:hidden to the container-xxl, certainly the page stops there, but there's missing information of the columns beyond the page, you can notice because the scroll bars goes further than the top of the page.

I know how to do it with JavaScript, but I'm sure there's a way to do it in CSS.

Something like this:

[image]

It's here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cptacco/pen/OJrPdEg)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-2" id="left">
      side bar menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 h-100 d-flex flex-column" id="right">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
           Header with some stuff ...
          <p>some stuff of the header</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row h-100" id="threecolumns" style="background-color:#fee">
        <div class="col-4 h-100 overflow-auto" style="background-color:#f2e">
          column with its own scroll
          <p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 h-100 overflow-auto" style="background-color:#d3e">
          column with its own scroll
          <p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 h-100 overflow-auto" style="background-color:#e4e">
          column with its own scroll
          <p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `100vh` to each of the column and add `overflow:hidden;` to the `container-xxl`

Comment: Then the overflow of the columns will be hidden not scrollable.

Comment: I've change the codepen with the "100vh to each column" change ... so you can see that the columns goes further the bottom.  If I add the overflow:hidden to the container-xxl, certainly the page stops there, but there's missing information of the columns beyond the page, you can notice because the scroll bars goes further than the top of the page